# Apply function to pandas sorting by a unique value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
> df_mm.sort('days').head(10)

     letters  days  count  key
0          c     1     10    1
2248       b     1    NaN  NaN
2376       b     1    NaN  NaN
2504       b     1    NaN  NaN
9996       a     1    NaN  NaN
2632       c     1     13    1
2736       c     1     23    1
9892       c     1     23    1
2840       d     1    NaN  NaN
2946       a     1    NaN  NaN
```

I want to apply `fillna()` to each group of rows grouped by a letter. IOW, do this:

```
df_mm[df_filled.letters == 'a'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

for each letter, and merge the results automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
print df.groupby('letters').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill'))
```

Sample (I modify `df` for testing):

```
print df
     letters  days  count  key
0          c     1     10    1
2248       b     1      5    7
2376       b     1    NaN  NaN
2504       b     1    NaN  NaN
9996       a     1     11   23
2632       c     1     13    1
2736       c     1     23    1
9892       c     1     23    1
2840       d     1    NaN  NaN
2946       a     1    NaN  NaN

print df.groupby('letters').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill'))
     letters  days  count  key
0          c     1     10    1
2248       b     1      5    7
2376       b     1      5    7
2504       b     1      5    7
9996       a     1     11   23
2632       c     1     13    1
2736       c     1     23    1
9892       c     1     23    1
2840       d     1    NaN  NaN
2946       a     1     11   23
```